# Easy way to figure out what is drawing in SpriteKit draw count

Tags: swift, count, sprite-kit, draw, sktilemapnode

I have the showdrawcount showing 20 draws at times and I'm trying to figure out what is causing the count to be so high, as I have all textures in atlas folders.

Is there an easy way to figure out what is causing each draw without removing nodes from the scene and re-running game?

Lastly, I'm using tilemapnodes. It appears that each tilemapnode consists of a draw, although the images in multiple tilemapnodes come from the same tileset. This makes no sense and makes me wonder if I should be using tilemapnodes at all, if It is going to increase the draw count with each tilemapnode. Is there a way to fix this or is this just how it works?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you doing this on simulator?  Remember our last issue with the draw count being different with assets folder and XCAssets folder?  This had to do with a bug in simulator, not xcode.

Comment: No, not in simulator. I still have my images all in .atlas folders and not within the xcassets folder

Comment: btw I can't imagine multiple tile sets all being drawn in 1 draw pass, unless maybe they were side by side

Comment: You are saying because they are overlapping it would require more passes? I can see that... Although with sprite nodes, I thought the demo Apple did showed this didn't matter. Would be nice if this applied to tile maps as well especially when the textures are coming from same tile sets and atlas files

Comment: Sprite nodes are different the tile maps,  It is not a bunch of sprite nodes that get tiled, it is optimized and I am thinking branched to handle the animations and other things

Comment: I get that they are different, just seems like some savings could be made if they optimized it. Since my tile maps are all 64x64 point tiles. I use them for  platforms or the ground... Would it be more beneficial to use sprite nodes instead of maps? The node count would increase drastically, but the draw count would decrease

Comment: That is a battle every programmer has to face,  Speed VS Memory Storage,  you want something to be faster,  generally it takes up more ram, and vice versa

Comment: Speed is my biggest concern if you got my last email about the slight stutter and lag issues I'm having... To be clear, using sprite nodes would be faster than tile maps in my case?

Comment: I haven't had a chance to look, that may just be optimization problems,  An increase in draw count would cause a consistent lag, not a stutter

Comment: Well appreciate the help here! definitely something I will consider...